# Opengraph image for pages in contao

Tags: templates, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, contao

I am working with the implementation of meta tags in contao. For this, I extended the fe_page template and added the meta tags there.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $this->title ?>">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{env::url}}/{{env::request}}"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?= $this->description ?>">
```

Similarly I need to display og:image property. But for contao pages, I hope there is no field for image upload in page settings. Is it possible to achieve og:image property for contao pages?. If yes, how it is possible?

Comment: What contao version? Contao 3 or 4?

Comment: What do you mean with "I hope there is no field for image upload in page settings"?

Comment: There is no separate field for image upload in page settings. Thats what I meant. Is that clear? So I just extended the page module for image upload field.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to simply install the [social_images](https://github.com/codefog/contao-social_images) extension. When enabled, it automatically adds teaser images from news and events as the `og:image` and it also allows you to define an `og:image` per page.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But what I did was, I extended the page module to form an image field and called this image in the og:image field.

Answer (score 0):

For Contao 4 you can also use the extension [numero2/contao-opengraph3](https://github.com/numero2/contao-opengraph3) - it will add new input fields in the page options for opengraph including a general og-image (individual per page) and optionally also a separate image for twitter cards.